# Use of SQL - IN in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a list of ids in python. For example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And i want to select a list of records in my (mysql ) data-base under the condition that the ids of these records are in x. something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN x
```

but I don't know who I can do this in python. I have seen some examples using %s in their sql string. However this does not work when the variable is a list. does anyone know how I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
'(%s)' % ','.join(map(str,x))
```

This will give you a string that you could use to send to MySql as a valid `IN` clause:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: Just be careful if x is the empty list because "IN ()" does not seem to be valid syntax (at least with SQL Server).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if all of those are known to be numbers of good standing, then you can simply call

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID IN ({0})".format(','.join(x))
```

If you know that they are numbers but *any* of them might have been from the user, then I might use:

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID IN ({0})".format(','.join(list(map(int,x))))
```

`format` will perform the replacement at the appropriate index. join is used so that you don't have the `[]`. list converts everything to a list, map applies a function to a list/tuple/iterable. In Python 3, however, map returns a generator, which isn't what you need. You need a list. So, list(map(x,y)) will return the list form of map(x,y).

Comment: It should be noted that Andrew's method works as well, but I prefer format as it is a more cross-lingual syntax.